# Page indicator in Carousel for Xamarin.Forms, it is possible?

Tags: carousel, swipe, indicator, xamarin.forms

I would like to show some page indicator in the Xamarin.Forms carousel, with dots or something similar.

The purpose is to let to the user know that there are more pages if he does swipe. The UX would improve a lot.

Any possibility/way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to implement the exact same thing and came across the following link:

http://chrisriesgo.com/xamarin-forms-carousel-view-recipe/

I found it quite easy to implement and figure out what is going on after reading through the post. A great option and well worked example in my opinion!

You'll only need to follow the example related to "Dots" of course :)

Hope this helps!